# Add Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio to Windows Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-terminal

How do I add the Visual Studio Developer's Command Prompt to the list of Windows Terminal consoles?

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Select** Settings, which will open a JSON file.

**Paste** the following to the array of profiles in the JSON, **changing** *2019* to *2017* and *Professional* to *Community* to match your install.

```
,
{
    "guid" : "{1748ecca-abdd-4aa4-bcc4-9fca0d045be5}",
    "name" : "VS cmd",
    "commandline" : "cmd.exe /k \"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat\"",
    "icon" : "ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}.png",
    "hidden": false
}
```

[image]

Comment: For Community version users, the command line is: "cmd.exe /k \"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\Common7\\Tools\\LaunchDevCmd.bat\""

Comment: Yeah, and mine was a little different as well - I split app installations across several drives so I can't use the %environment variable% thing and hard code it: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat

Comment: And for VS2019 community x64 version, the command line is: "cmd.exe /k \"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat\""

Comment: For enterprise version, use `"cmd.exe /k \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise\\Common7\\Tools\\vsdevcmd.bat\""`

Answer (score 8):

The answer from Wallace Kelly is great, but the settings below may be a useful copy/paste for others who want Visual Studio icons, both x86 and x64 and a less DOS-like font.

As with Wallace's answer, adjust "2019" and "Professional", e.g. for 2017/Community, as needed.

[image]

```
{
  "guid": "{9a3a9308-d6f8-4b1d-896c-a27c59c28be3}",
  "name": "VS2019 x86",
  "commandline": "cmd.exe /k cd c:/dev/mc-hardware-svc/out/vs-x86-Debug && \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars32.bat\"",
  "fontFace": "Consolas",
  "fontSize": 10,
  "icon" : "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/Assets/VisualStudio.70x70.contrast-black_scale-80.png",
  "hidden": false
},
{
  "guid": "{ceec68f2-0ef7-48f0-84db-4693612532cd}",
  "name": "VS2019 x64",
  "commandline": "cmd.exe /k \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat\"",
  "icon" : "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/Assets/VisualStudio.70x70.contrast-black_scale-80.png",
  "hidden": false
},
```

Answer (score 7):

For VS 2022 Community:

```
{
  "name": "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022",
  "commandline": "powershell.exe -noe -c \"&{$vsPath = &(Join-Path ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} '\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\vswhere.exe') -property installationpath; Import-Module (Join-Path $vsPath 'Common7\\Tools\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'); Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath $vsPath -SkipAutomaticLocation}\"",
  "icon": "%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\Assets\\VisualStudio.70x70.contrast-standard_scale-180.png"
},
{
  "name": "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022",
  "commandline": "%comspec%  /k \"%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat\"",
  "icon": "%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\Assets\\VisualStudio.70x70.contrast-standard_scale-180.png"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

VisualStudio developer prompts are now in Windows Terminal stable (1.12)! https://twitter.com/mrhestew/status/1489322750330085380

```
winget upgrade -e Microsoft.WindowsTerminal
```